# Error connecting to MySQL with Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Why is this code failling?

```py
import mysql.connector as mysql

db = mysql.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = "root",
    passwd='root'
)
```

I'm running this code online, i.e., on binder.

Whenever I try I get "DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)".

What could be the problem?

Comment: The code is fine check your MySQL sever.

Comment: OK, but how can I do that on binder? And what should I do to check?

Comment: I don't know about binder but if the MySQL server is on the same machine as the script it should run fine with localhost.

Comment: that is what has been bugging me... in theory both are on the same machine, I think so...